# DjangoRestFramework - pass partial flag to nested serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How do I pass `partial` flag to nested serializers ?

for example , serializers.py

```
class ASerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        print("A", self.partial)
        return data


class BSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    a = ASerializer(read_only=False)

    def validate(self, data):
        print("B", self.partial)
        return data
```

views.py

```
class TestView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {}
        return Response(content)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        bsr = BSerializer(data=request.data, partial=True) # <- I want to pass the partial flag to the nested serializer as well
        if bsr.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            return Response(bsr.data)
        else:
            return Response(bsr.error)
```

passing `{"a":{"name":"test"}}` to TestView  prints

```
A False
B True
```

In this example how do I pass the partial flag to ASerializer from BSerializer ?

edit:
This is how I am using the partial flag, basically to do partial validation and perform updates. In this case if partial is false. username, password and user_type must be provided.

Validate function of the nested serialzer

```
def validate(self, data):

    username = data.get("username")
    password = data.get("password")
    user_type = intTryParse(data.get("user_type"))

    if self.partial:
        # validation for update
        if len(data.keys()) == 0:
            msg = _("Empty attribute set")
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code="authorization")

        elif password:
            msg = _("Password changing not allowed from this api")
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code="authorization")

        elif username or user_type:
            msg = _("Cannot edit username and user_type")
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code="authorization")
    else:
        # validation for create
        if username and password and user_type:
            if CustomUser.objects.filter(username=username,).exists():
                msg = _("Username is not available")
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code="authorization")
        else:
            msg = _('Must include "username", "password" and "user_type".')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code="authorization")
    return data
```

Comment: What behaviour do you expect from `partial` being passed on? I believe using a context may be of help

Comment: @Benoît I have added my use case, I'll add more code/explanation if required. I am also open to suggestions on better ways of doing this.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how safe this is but overriding the init method seems to do the job.

```
class BSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    a = ASerializer(read_only=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["a"].partial = self.partial # <- update the partial flag here

    def validate(self, data):
        print("B", self.partial)
        return data
```